# Can "Poll Mailbox Trigger"-Plugin start a Pipeline-Job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

The Poll Mailbox Plugin works perfectly fine with a Freestyle-Project and triggers automatically my Jenkins jobs. But I need to trigger Pipeline-Jobs. How can I trigger them via mail?

What I tried:

- I already tried the same configurations as the Freestyle-Project for the Pipeline-Jobs. The result was that the mailserver retrieved my mails but didn't trigger an build.
- I researched for any other solutions in the web, but I found nothing about it.